# Не определяет Bot.say

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

Пишу бота дискорд на Python 3.7.1
Код:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот готов к работе')

@Bot.command(pass_context= True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await Bot.say("hello")

Bot.run("NjA0OTYxNjEwODM0MTE2NjI0.XT114A.BUld2NI5c9VWhG7BwjDKBRP6F1U")
```

И ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command hello:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 13, in hello
    await Bot.say("hello")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'say'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'say'
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Третья строчка ( с импорт Бот) не нужна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению модуль "discord.py" не работает на версиях выше 3.6.0. Если установите версию ниже всё будет работать, так как код верный.
(В будущем не указывайте строки кода с токеном на публику, вам могут сделать гадости при желании)

Comment: Спасибо, то есть ставлю к примеру 3.5+ но не выше 3.6.0, да?

Comment: Кстати я другой токен сделал, всё хорошо)

Comment: Python 3.5.4 подойдёт?

Comment: Да, должено заработать, предотвращаю ещё один возмозможный вопрос,если установите 2 различные версии python, не забудьте поменять путь в системе, тут наглядно http://prntscr.com/oll3e3